# How to extract d@u from 'From richard.richrdqwd@uct.za.ca' using non-greedy regular expression?

Tags: python

I'm quite new to regular expressions in Python.

So I'm wondering how can I extract `d@u` from the text below using non-greedy expressions?

```
x = 'From richard.richrdqwd@uct.za.ca'
```

Thank you in advance!

Any suggestion would be appreciated

Comment: This is not a well stated problem. What do you want? Just `d@u`? Then you don't need regexp. Any two characters surrounding `@`? Then use `.@.` regexp. This may be useful for you: https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
import re
m = re.search('.@.', 'From richard.richrdqwd@uct.za.ca')
if m:
    print(m.group(0))
```